# How to update row data of google spreadsheet using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am facing a problem on how to update the row of data in my database(google spreadsheet) using Google app script. Basically, I have a cell in the spreadsheet that has the value "Pending Approval" in it. When the script is executed, I want it to change the value in that cell to "Approved". I did lot of search but I can't figure out, how to do it correctly. I am newbie in this. Hope you can help me. Thanks!

**Code.gs**

```
 function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('17lKIhONfEeNogsBhKtGr4zVaLgH0_199-3J3-0tAdcE')
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}

function setApproved(ldap) 
{
 // set the correct id and get the database
 var id= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId('17lKIhONfEeNogsBhKtGr4zVaLgH0_199-3J3-0tAdcE');
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet();

 // Get all the data from the sheet
 var data = sss.getDataRange().getValues();

 // Get the headers and get the index of the ldap and the approval status
 // using the names you use in the headers
 var headers = data[0];
 var ldapIndex = headers.indexOf('ldap'); 
 var statusIndex = headers.indexOf('approvalstatus');

 // Declare the variable for the correct row number
 var sheetRow;

 // Iterate data, look for the correct row checking the ldap, start from 1 as 0==headers
 for( var i = 1 ; i < data.length; i++ )
 {
   var row = data[i];
   if(row[ldapIndex] == ldap)
   { 
     // You have found the correct row, set + 1 because Sheet range starts from 1, not 0
     sheetRow = i +1;
     // We have found the row, no need to iterate further
     break;
   }
}
 // Also set statusIndex +1, because index in array is -1 compared to index in sheet
 ++statusIndex;
 //Set the value
 sss.getRange(sheetRow, statusIndex ).setValue('Approved'); 
}
```

**Index.html**

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div  id="tables">
      <? var data = getData();?>
      <table style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid; float: left; " id="tableShift1">
      <caption style="">Shift1</caption>
          <th style="border:2px solid black;">   Ldap   </th>
          <th style="border:2px solid black;">   Date   </th>
          <th style="border:2px solid black;">   Action   </th>
        <? for (var dataList = 1; dataList < data.length; dataList++) {
             ?>
          <tr >
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><?= data[dataList][0] ?></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><?= Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[dataList][1]),"GMT+800", "yyyy-MM-dd"); ?></td>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;"><button onclick='setApproved()' id='ldap'>Approve</button> <button onclick='functionDecline()' id='button1'>Decline</button></td>
          </tr>
        <?   
          } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
  </body>
 <script>
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your database have headers ? Do your entries have an id or other unique information? Edit: viewing again, I presume ldap does not occur in the database twice, correct?

Comment: my database have header and no ids. my headers are: Timestamp, ldap(name), date(the date want to approve), and the status of the data("Approved"/"Declined").

Comment: Ok, but every ldap occurs only once in the database, right? Also just to make sure: every row has a cell that says pending approval or there is just one single cell that needs to be set?

Comment: Those ldap are the name of the user who plotted for approval. The "cell" means is the Column and Row of that data right?

Comment: Right! So I suppose one ldap does not have to be approved twice, which means it can be used as id?

Comment: thats right maam/sir

Comment: do i need to put ID header? which may indicate that data will be edit only. not all ldap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, as you have tagged the question as Google-App-Script, I presume you know how to call the function from the client side.

So as the ldap does not occur in the database twice, you could use it as an id with a function like following:

```
function setApproved(ldap) 
{
 // set the correct id and get the database
 var id= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getActiveSheet();

 // Get all the data from the sheet
 var data = sss.getDataRange().getValues();

 // Get the headers and get the index of the ldap and the approval status
 // using the names you use in the headers
 var headers = data[0];
 var ldapIndex = headers.indexOf('ldap'); 
 var statusIndex = headers.indexOf('approvalstatus');

 // Declare the variable for the correct row number
 var sheetRow;

 // Iterate data, look for the correct row checking the ldap, start from 1 as 0==headers
 for( var i = 1 ; i < data.length; i++ )
 {
   var row = data[i];
   if(row[ldapIndex] == ldap)
   { 
     // You have found the correct row, set + 1 because Sheet range starts from 1, not 0
     sheetRow = i +1;
     // We have found the row, no need to iterate further
     break;
   }
}
 // Also set statusIndex +1, because index in array is -1 compared to index in sheet
 ++statusIndex;
 //Set the value
 sss.getRange(sheetRow, statusIndex ).setValue('Approved'); 
}
```

I hope something like above works for you, did for me. 
I hope it is not too messy either, a quick example I came up with. 
Do let me know if you have any questions !

EDIT: I added the 'break' to the loop, as I forgot it first and seems it already backfired for you.

EDIT: I will add an image for an example. The sheet demonstrates what kind of sheet is used for the example and what the sheet looks like after I have once run    setApproved('jaska')     :
[image: example]

Comment: Timestamp Ldap Date Status
2/1/2018 3:59:09 1a 2/1/2018 Approved
1/31/2018 4:00:12 2a 2/2/2018 
1/31/2018 4:06:12 3p 2/5/2018 Approved
1/31/2018 4:06:16 4a 2/5/2018 
1/31/2018 4:06:21 5p 2/6/2018 
1/31/2018 4:06:25 6p 2/1/2018 Approved
1/31/2018 4:06:28 7p 2/1/2018 
1/31/2018 4:06:31 8a 2/2/2018 
1/31/2018 4:06:36 9a 2/12/2018 Approved
1/31/2018 4:06:40 10a 2/12/2018 
1/31/2018 4:06:44 11a 2/14/2018

Comment: Ok now, I have to wait a little longer before I comment :D Ok, so What does your comment mean ? Is that the outcome? How do you call your function and did you set the change the header names according to your own sheet?

Comment: yes i changed it according to my headers. but still not working. wondering on what function functionApprove(ldap) ´ldap´ came from or how it will works. is your work is same with my html? can you please show your whole coding(the Code.gs and the Index.html)? im too curious about what did you do on your work, so that i can understand carefully what you did. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Im getting error - TypeError: Cannot call method "getId" of null. (line 18, file "Code")

var id= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

Comment: You should enter the id as you did your example. My guess is that you have not linked the script to a Spreadsheet but are doing a standalone script? Then the activesheet.getId() won't work.  I'll try to work out a full example to share with you ! What is your experience with Javascript anyway? Can you work out the javascript to call the Google App Script function with correct ldap as parameter?

Comment: Dont have much knowledge in javascript. Im doing it in script.google.com and my database is the google spreadsheet. Actually, im working with my project for my work. Im creating a web based for plotting a VL(vacation leave).  The process of that should be, *back end part* the approver will see those employee who plotted their VL. Then the approver may approve or decline. And for the employee, they can only view those approved VLs with the calendar interface. So im working with the back end first. But i am newbee with this, all i know are basics. So i create an account here to have resources.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong. To call the function is I need to use "onclick()  method right? <td><button onclick='setApproved()' id='ldap'>Approve</button>. And when the button excetute, the "function setApproved(ldap)" will excecute. Then the "ldap" in "setApproved(ldap)" is the id of that button, am I right?

Comment: I edited the code above. Please see where i am wrong.

Comment: I put the id of the spreadsheet but still getting error of TypeError: Cannot call method "getId" of null.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<td style="border:1px solid black;"><button onclick='google.script.run.setApproved("<?= data[dataList][0] ?>")' id='ldap'>Approve</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use getId() to get the Id because you already know.

var id = '17lKIhONfEeNogsBhKtGr4zVaLgH0_199-3J3-0tAdcE';

- On your Index.html I observed that you did not use google.script.run to call a function to the server
  google.script.run.setApproved([parameter])
- Your onclick() function call did not pass any parameter.

  `<td style="border:1px solid black;"><button onclick='google.script.run.setApproved("jack")' id='ldap'>Approve</button> </td>`

Answer (score -1):

I found a easy and quick solution. Just change this:

`var id= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId('17lKIhONfEeNogsBhKtGr4zVaLgH0_199-3J3-0tAdcE');`

To this:

`var id= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId('17lKIhONfEeNogsBhKtGr4zVaLgH0_199-3J3-0tAdcE').getSheetByName('NAME_OF_UR_SHEET');`